# Why does my Babylonian Algorithm 2 not work for n=65?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int n; 
    float x = n/2;
    printf("enter the number to find the square root of:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (x - n/x > 0.01) 
    { 
        x = (x + n/x) / 2; 

    } 

    printf("Square root of %d is %f\n", n, x); 
    getchar(); 
}
```

The above code works fine for values ***n=1 to 64***; however  from ***n=65*** the output gets stuck at ***x=8***. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: You probably meant to do floating point division? `float x = n/2.0f;` and so on.

Comment: @adi99 What is this     int n; 
    float x = n/2; ?! The variable n is not initialized.

Comment: Why dont you do a binary search to find your squareroot?

Comment: Seems much cleaner to do: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int n = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 10; ...` Parameters should not be taken from input, but from the command line.

Comment: @WilliamPursell why?

Comment: `echo pattern-to-match | grep path`.  Try making that useful!  Parameters should be passed a arguments, not read from the input stream.

Comment: @vikAy Binary search is slower.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to rearrange some lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter the number to find the square root of: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // this got moved after the scanf
    float x = n / 2.0;
    while (x - n / x > 0.01) {
        x = (x + n / x) / 2;
    }
    printf("Square root of %d is %f\n", n, x);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Can You please explain as to why it needs to be moved?

Comment: `n` isn't initialized if you put it before the `scanf`, which means that it could be any value.